# Location Updates available but disabled

Tags: android, android-location

I experience a strange problem. I just implemented a location client to retrieve users position like in the doc: [**Retrieving the Current Location**](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

To test the error dialog if no connection is available I enabled flight mode and disabled location services.

```
int resultCode =
          GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
```

However this code returns a `ConnectionResult.SUCCESS`. When I try to get the location I get null but shouldn't the `resultCode` return some error (as they say in the doc)? Any ideas where the problem is? My code is mostly the same as in the doc example.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong on this but I believe since Google Play Services is not just for location services (ie. you can still do [Activity Recognition](http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html) without access to the users location) it should still return `ConnectionResult.SUCCESS`. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html), the `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` basically checks if Play Services is installed and on the correct version required for your app.

In order to check for availability of user location you still have to check the `isProviderEnabled` on the `LocationManager` class.